# Clone an existing MobileFrist Platform Foundation (MFP) V8 environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How do I create a clone of a MFP V8 environment? The clone will have the same topology, with foundation server and database Oracle server on a new host. We have three oracle databases for MFP Core, Admin and App Center.  Then we have our major Analytics file based database. We also plan to apply the latest ifix on the foundation server and the underline Liberty server.

Answer (score 0):

High level steps for moving the runtime would be

1. Install Oracle on new host.
2. Move data from current DB to new DB.
3. Install Liberty on new host.
4. Install MFP on new host.
5. Run Server configuration tool or ant tasks to configure the runtime
   environment (point to the new liberty and new Oracle instance)
6. Restart liberty server.

Please note the important update in MFP8.0 IFIX release notes here -
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/03/09/8-0-ifix-release/

Regarding analytics data movement, please consider the following points

1. In an analytics Cluster, the indivdual nodes stores data under a
   folder configured via jndi property called  analytics/datapath  - By
   default on every node it is under ./analyticsData directory. (within the
   MFP Analytics location)
2. If you are moving data from an one Cluster to a new Analytics
   Cluster, make sure the cluster has same number of nodes.
3. Copy of analytics data should follow below pattern (make sure the
   servers nodes are stopped while copying to avoid any lock files in
   place)

Node-1 of Old Analytics Server ---> Node-1 of New Analytics Server
Node-2 of Old Analytics Server ---> Node-2 of New Analytics Server
... and so on...

Make sure the ./analyticsData directory on the new analytics cluster
nodes are empty and the nodes are stopped.

4. Make sure the analyticsData copied to the new machine holds the same 
   directory structure as before in the previous cluster nodes. (By default
   analyticsData directory contains a directory called worklight) Keep the 
   structure same.
5. Make sure the analytics JNDI properties are set as similar to the old
   machine (node IPs can be changed thats fine according to new machines) -
   especially the analytics server.xml
6. Start the new analytics nodes and verify the data. (make sure on the 
   analytics console, the date filter is set corrrectly to view the data).

Important Note: Make sure a backup of all the node-wise analyticsData is
kept safe. Use of tar.gz is better for copy of data from node to node.